# Chromium - Function is not defined .. after some hours

Tags: javascript, chromium

i'm developing a vending machine based on local web pages in Chromium on ARM Linux machine.

Chromium version 63.

Basically it is a single web page with two div tags: *vending div* and *advertising div* (with small videos). They switch from the first to second one 
(and return) by a timer or a user touch.

In the switching procedure I recall two functions called **startVideo()** and **stopVideo()** to start or stop video control in the advertising div.

Everything run correctly switching between pages for some hours. After that I start to see wrong behavior and in the console I have errors like the following:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: stopVideo is not defined
```

and

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: startVideo is not defined
```

How it is possible?

Comment: Where do you define `stopVideo` and `startVideo`?

Comment: In a separate js file included in the main file

Comment: Check the network tab and make sure that js file is loaded correctly.

Comment: But the code is running correctly since hours. It must be loaded ..

Comment: It must not be loaded, otherwise `stopVideo` and `startVideo` would be defined. Please check the network tab and report back.

Comment: The functions are recalled correctly until 3 minutes before the error, so they are loaded. I'm wondering if they could be unloaded for some reasons ..

Comment: I'm not sure if there is enough information here to help you. Please try to include more details about your setup, configuration etc

Comment: I think that the machine had a bad SD memory cause the problem was no more seen